# 'All but finite' and 'infinitely many'

Tags: real-analysis

There are two phrases in Mathematics: '*All but finite*' and '*infinitely many*'. I have some confusion between them.

Suppose $P(n)$ is a statement. If we say that $P(n)$ is true for all but finite number of values of $n$, it means it is true for all values of $n$ except a finite number of values of $n$.

If $P(n)$ is true for infinitely many number of values of $n$, so does it mean that it is true for all values of $n$ except infinite values of $n$?

Comment: "If P(n) is true for infinitely many number of values of n, so does it mean that it is true for all values of n except infinite values of n?" No, this means that the set of n such that P(n) is true is infinite. For example, P(n) = [n is greater than 100] is true except for finitely many nonnegative integers n, but Q(n) = [n is prime] is true for infinitely many n and is false also for infinitely many n, hence P(n) is true for all but finite number of values of n, but not Q(n)... (Your interpretation of "P(n) is true for all but finite number of values of n" is correct.)

Comment: In case of 'all but finite', number of exceptions are finite. Likewise, in case of 'infinitely many', what about number of exceptions? Are they finite or infinite??

Comment: There has got to be a comparison of Venn diagrams somewhere illustrating this.

Comment: @Priyanka: Yes.  The number of exceptions may be finite or infinite, the statement "true for infinitely many" does not tell you anything about the preimage of false.

Comment: Math is not poetry. A sentence means what it says, and no more.

Comment: @Priyanka Sorry but your comment seems to indicate that you did NOT read mine.

Comment: I have read your comment Did, I was little confused. Is every statement which is true for all but finite values of n, also true for infinitely many values of n?

Answer (score 4):

If something is true of all positive **even** numbers $2,4,6,8,10,12,\ldots$, and not true of odd numbers, then it is true of **infinitely many** of the positive integers $1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$.

But it is **not** that case that it's true of all except finitely many, since the set of numbers of which it is not true --- the odd numbers --- is not finite.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider thinking of it like this.

Suppose $P$ is true for "all but finitely many objects". Then you can actually *list* those objects: $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n$ all fail to have property $P$.

Now you might ask, does $P$ hold for infinitely many objects? You can probably see that it will only be true if the domain we're talking about is infinite: If $P$ is a property of the integers, then finitely many "bad" cases gives us infinitely many "good" cases.

But we could also be working over a finite domain in some special situations. Suppose we're studying Woozzle integers, a special subset of the integers just discovered. We want to know how many Woozzle integers have property $P$. But the weird thing is, no one knows how many Woozzle integers there are yet. So while someone could reasonably prove that $P$ holds for all but finitely many Woozzle integers, you could *not* then conclude that it holds for infinitely many of them, since it's not clear there even *are* infinitely many.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, given statements $P(n)$ hold for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ means that there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ implies $P(n)$ holds; the statements $P(n)$ hold for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ means that for every $N \geq 1$ there is some $n > N$ such that $P(N)$ holds.